# How to sum values of array in each dimension into one matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I've one array with three dimensions and want to sum up the values in each dimension and end up with one data matrix.

Here is one example:

```
array1 <- array(c(-5.5,6,3),dim = c(3,4,3))  

matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=3, ncol=4)

matrix
       [,1]   [,2]  [,3]   [,4]
[1,]  -16.5  -16.5 -16.5  -16.5
[2,]   18      18    18     18
[3,]    9       9     9      9
```

Is it possible to do it somehow with a loop instead of using any apply function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want a loop and not one of the `apply` functions?

Comment: How you would do it with a 'apply' function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to sum along each dimension? Your example shows summation along the third dimension.

Anyway, this is how it could be done (you made it explicit that you didn't want to use `apply`):

```
X <- array(c(-5.5,6,3), dim = c(3,4,3))

rows <- dim(X)[1]
cols <- dim(X)[2]

result <- matrix(0, nrow=rows, ncol=cols)
for (i in seq(rows)) {
  for (j in seq(cols)) {
    result[i,j] <- sum(X[i,j,])
  }
}
```

gives you

```
> result

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] -16.5 -16.5 -16.5 -16.5
[2,]  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0
[3,]   9.0   9.0   9.0   9.0
```

**EDIT:** Since you asked (but I would advise against this solution as it is slow and certainly not the idiomatic way to do all this in R):

```
result <- matrix(0, nrow=rows, ncol=cols)
for (i in seq(rows)) {
  for (j in seq(cols)) {
    for (k in seq(dim(X)[3])) {
      result[i,j] <- result[i,j] + X[i,j,k]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `result` has been initialized with zeroes. If that weren't the case, you'd have to initialize it between the `j` and `k` loops.

Comment: Indeed, only along the third dimension.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you mind accepting the answer then? ;-)

Comment: Just one more question how would the script look like if I want to work without function "sum". For example if I want to subtract values or do sth else?

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could add another inner `for`-loop with e.g. a variable `k` that indexes the last dimension of the array. You could then accumulate or subtract or whatever it is you want to do with the values.

Answer (score 14):

Your question says you don't want to use an `apply` function, but in case you change your mind, you specify the margin as `c(1, 2)`:

```
apply(array1, MARGIN=c(1, 2), sum)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
# [1,] -16.5 -16.5 -16.5 -16.5
# [2,]  18.0  18.0  18.0  18.0
# [3,]   9.0   9.0   9.0   9.0
```

Comment: @burton030, Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by '*how does it works without using "sum"*'. What is the exact problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry for being so imprecisely. I mean how would you use apply if you want subtract the third dimensions or do some other calculations?

Comment: @burton030, I suppose you can use anonymous functions. `Reduce` might also come in handy: `apply(array1, c(1, 2), function(x) Reduce(`-`, x))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function `tapply`
by example here, we would like to know the sum by cells of 5 matrix include in an array.

- Create your `array`

  ```
  X<-array(1:15,dim(3,3,5)) #now you have an array with 3 dims
  ```
- now you would like to apply a sum on all 5 matrix in your 3rd dim

  ```
  npix <-dim(X)[1]*dim(X)[2] #calculate the number of cells

  result<-tapply(X[,,,], rep(1:npix,dim(X)[3]), FUN=function(x) {sum(na.omit(x))})
  ```