# R: How to build sum of arrays third dimension containing NAs and returning a list?

Tags: arrays, r, apply

I want to build the sum of the third dimension of an array. Here some example data (with 3d names, which are important):

```
my.array <- array(1:24, dim=c(3,4,2))
dimnames(my.array)[[3]] <- c("111.2012", "112.2012")
```

As I want a list as an output, I would do this (according to [Ananda Mahto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302052/how-to-sum-values-of-array-in-each-dimension-into-one-matrix)), which works fine with this example (and keeps the names):

```
as.list(apply(my.array, MARGIN=c(3), sum))
```

However, not on an array containing NAs. Here an example:

```
my.arrayNA <- array(c(NA,1,NA,5,6,3,NA,5), dim=c(2,2,2))
```

I tried using `na.rm=TRUE` as below without success.

```
as.list(apply(my.arrayNA, function(x) MARGIN=c(3), sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Ideas how to get the sum? Thanks

Comment: `as.list(apply(my.arrayNA, MARGIN=3, function(x)  sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)))` MARGIN has to be a parameter of `apply()`. Or simply: `as.list(apply(my.arrayNA, MARGIN=3, FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE))`. Or even shorter: `as.list(apply(my.arrayNA, 3, sum, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: You now have two answers. So eventually you want to accept a answer  by clicking next to the voting. Or you can comment why the answers aren't  what you desired.

Answer (score 2):

How about transforming the NA values into 0's first:

```
my.arrayNA[is.na(my.arrayNA)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
as.list(apply(my.arrayNA, MARGIN=3, function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

MARGIN has to be a parameter of `apply()`! Or simply:

```
as.list(apply(my.arrayNA, MARGIN=3, FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Or even shorter:

```
as.list(apply(my.arrayNA, 3, sum, na.rm=TRUE))
```